# Azure text-to-speech is not accessable in Windows 2012 r2

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azuretls12/ - here MS says that they are going to switch to tls12, it is okey. Win2012r2 support this version of TLS.
2. Here the list of cipher that win10 supports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10--version-1507

   It contains following ciphers suites

   ```
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
   ```
3. Here the list of cipher that win2012r8 (aka win8.1) supports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1

   It does not contain the cipher suites from above
4. And this is Azure endpoint of text-to-speech API: https://southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1

   With help of this utils https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan i have scanned the site above to see what cipher suites it supports

   ```
   > sslscan.exe --tls1.2 southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com
   ...
   Connected to 20.43.132.2
   Testing SSL server southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com on port 443 using SNI name southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com
   ...
   Supported Server Cipher(s):
   Preferred TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253 <<< win10 only
   Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve 25519 DHE 253 <<< win10 only
   Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305   Curve 25519 DHE 253 <<< non-win at all
   ...
   ```

It appears that text-to-speech TLS supports only three suites:

- one is not supported by any windows version,
- and other two are supported only by windows 10

So win2012 server is not supported by azure text-to-speech. Does anybody know how to handle this situation w/o throwing my 2012 servers out?

---

UPDATE as for 2020-10-04 the scanning gives five cipher suites:

```
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve 25519 DHE 253
```

Last two ones are supported by win2012r2 (and by win2008r2). So for now problem is resolved by MS.

Comment: Was this working in the past, but break recently?

Comment: @splusq Yes, exactly.

Comment: we expect a resolution in the next 1-2 days.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, the scan is returning win 2012 r2 supported ciphers

Comment: this seems more appropriate to be a comment as it does not have anything that helps the question.